# Error using mex: No supported compiler or SDK was found

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, compiler-errors, mex

Despite the fact that I get the following message by typing `mex -setup`:

```
>> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. In the near future
     you will be required to update your code to utilize the
     new API. You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
```

When I want to compile a certain `.cpp` file, I get the following error:

```
>> mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp cvm_em64t_debug.lib
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2015a/win64.html.
```

Comment: Compiling `.cpp` file uses C++ compiler. Use `mex -setup C++`, for setting up C++ compiler.

Comment: @Rotem that doesn't make any difference. I've used mex a lot of times.

Comment: Either you dont have a supported compiler or there is a bug and you need to contact mathworks. 99% sure its the first one

Comment: @Rotem I'm using it on another system now. that was several days ago. any way, despite my first comment, your solution did work. do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling `.cpp` file uses C++ compiler (`.c` file uses C compiler).
Use `mex -setup C++`, for setting up C++ compiler.

Apparently source file extension does matter when using `mex` instruction...